# Display phtml file inside phtml file in Magento

Tags: xml, magento, layout, plugins

I am using magento and have set up a plugin but there are a few changes I would like to make to how it is displayed and in order to do so I need the following issue solved. 
I have media.phtml in which I am calling another phtml file belonging to a plugin but for whatever reason the phtml file belonging to the plugin is not rendered.

I call the file in media.phtml with the following code:

```
    echo $this->getChildHtml('mynewblock');
```

This is referencing the following code in catalog.xml:

```
    <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media"    template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml">
                <reference name="content">
                    <block type="base/default_template_rwpproductvideo" name="product.mynewblock" as="mynewblock" template="base/default/template/rwproductvideo/video.phtml"/>
                </reference>
            </block>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" translate="label">
                <label>Alert Urls</label>
            </block>
```

I should mention I also tried calling it using;

```
    include('app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rwproductvideo/video.phtml');
```

Which gave an error on the page

There has been an error processing your request

Invalid method RocketWeb_ProductVideo_Block_Product_View_Media::_getProductVideos(Array
(
)
)

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml">
   <reference name="content">           
       <block type="productvideo/video" name="product.info.media.video" as="mynewblock" template="rwproductvideo/video.phtml"/>
   </reference>
</block>
<block type="core/text_list" name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" translate="label">
   <label>Alert Urls</label>
</block>
```

See I have given type as 'productvideo/video' for 'mynewblock' block.

You need to refer some tutorials how to call blocks

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer but it's still not displaying. Should I still call it using -  echo $this->getChildHtml('mynewblock');

Comment: Apologies, it is displaying but in the wrong part of the page. I'm sure I can fix that myself. Thanks very much, I tried to up-vote your answer but it says I'm not allowed because I don't have enough points myself :/